# Php/Mysql game: how to implement over the time upgrades

Tags: php, mysql

I'm starting to design a basic php game, with some properties which can be upgrated over the time.

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement it (and the database as well)
I was think of something like this:

PlayerID    |    Property1    |    Property1_isUpdating(bool)  |   Property1_Timeout(date)

but I have to create 2 extra fields per player's attribute.

Or I could just use a date as a timeout, and when the player connects, I check and update what I need.. but it doesn't seem to be good either.

I'm almost sure there is "one good way" to do it.. (and almost sure it isn't those mentioned before)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
PlayerId | PropertyId | UpgradingTo | UpgradeCompleteAt
```

This gives you the option to have multiple upgrade paths as well. **Each game tick**, go through your buildings where `UpgradingTo <> NULL AND UpgradeComplateAt < currentTime()` and set `PropertyId = UpgradingTo` and `UpgradingTo = null`. You can optionally reset UpgradeCompleteAt, but it might be a useful mechanic to keep it. For example "You can only upgrade property X to property Y if it has been X for at least 3 days" would add an interesting element.

*Note if you don't have a game tick, I'd make one. It's essentially something that loops every X amount of time, could be every 0.1 seconds, could be every minute.

Comment: Hey, first thank you for answering.

I like your idea but I'm concerned about the idea of having a script running every X seconds to update those properties. I mean, if I got a descent amount of players, this script will make my server goes crazy.. just to update properties.

Problem is: I don't know if I can find something which doesn't need a script like this. So I will think a little bit more about it. 
Anyway thanks a lot for your time glowcoder

Comment: Most games have some sort of a game tick. Even real time games have one. If you ran it every X seconds, that might be slow because of the spawning of the interpreter, threads, etc. If you had one script that ran on game boot, and then just slept for (X seconds - timeTakenToRunLastIteration) it will be much more efficient. I've been involved (managed or programmed) over a dozen games, and not one, even a php-web based game, was without a game tick. :-)

Comment: I like your idea, the only thing which annoys me is the fact that my properties are from now on, separated from the user. If I need to add a property, i'll have to create X new records (and not just add a simple field with a default value)
I think I'm gonna give a shot anyway.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @radigou that's not true necessarily true. If you wanted them all on the player table you could. `playerId | playerName | class | hp | magic | prop1Status | prop1UpdatingTo | prop1UpgradeCompleteAt | prop2Status ...` Another thing to keep in mind is that you could group the properties together. For example, `TABLE PaladinProperties... TABLE KnightProperties... TABLE JediProperties` - After all, a Paladin doesn't need Jedi properties. So if you add a new Jedi property, you just add it to the `JediProperty` table. You don't have to create a new record for each `Jedi` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create separate table for properties with fields

id, player_id, property, is_updated, timeout, property_type

And update a specific property in this table.

Another approach is store all property in players table in xml field format:

<property1 name="" is_updatied="1" timeoute="0">
<property2 name="" is_updatied="1" timeout="0">

And use mysql extractValue function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue

Comment: And how will you know when your upgrade is complete for this?

Comment: I miss that timeout is date field. So edited my answer. Anyway this one is only approach you can add any additional fields(attributes)

Comment: So, what is the difference between `property` and `property_type`?

Comment: I agree, I would definitely need a separate table to store properties and their improvements. However, I don't really get the solution you provide for the update. Should I use a script every X seconds? (It could slow down my server quite a lot)
Thank you both for your time